# Filter HTML tags from content only for searching, not displaying in Solr

Tags: html, indexing, solr, lucene

I have a content field called `Overview` in my source data that I am storing in a text field in Solr called `tm_overview` (why it's multivalue I have no clue, but it was done before my arrival), which is a standard text field. I am having a problem where numbers and text from the HTML tags are being found during searching. For example, searching on `166` finds this text and returns a record:

```
<img height=\"166\" src=\"[custom:asset-url]/6004064a_laser_dstnc_meter_emph_250x131_0.jpg\" width=\"250\" />
```

So obviously, I need to strip the HTML tags and their content from the field content, and it looks like the tool to do it is the [HTMLCharFilterFactory](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/charfilterfactories.html). The field has both `indexed` and `stored` set to `true`, so as I understand it, the content will be indexed using the index analyzer as defined in the `<fieldType>` definition in `schema.xml`, and then when the field is returned, it will return the data as it was originally stored (which is what I want).

Using a test index, I have created the following `<fieldType>` definition in  `schema_extra_types.xml`.

```
<fieldType name="text_cjk" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <charFilter class="solr.HTMLStripCharFilterFactory"/>
        <!--<charFilter class="solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory" pattern="#strong" replacement="" />-->
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.ICUTokenizerFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CJKBigramFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.CJKWidthFilterFactory"/>
        <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The values being passed into the field look like this:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td align="center">
            <figure class="center"><img height="166" src="[custom:asset-url]/F_tix520_05a_250x147_0.jpg" width="250" /></figure>

            <div class="small-font">更快地导航、捕捉和处理图像</div>
            </td>
            <td>
            ...
```

or even just paragraph text:

```
<p><strong>This infrared camera gives you easier angles with a 240° rotating screen and broader temperature range</strong></p>

<p>The blah blah product will help you easily navigate over, under and around hard to reach targets with the full 240° rotating screen. You can capture and process images quickly and analyze images in the field on the 5.7 inch responsive touchscreen LCD with on-camera analytics. Save time by editing emissivity, background temp, transmissivity, palettes, color alarms, adjusting IR-Fusion, and enabling/disabling markers all on the camera.</p>
```

However, none of the tags are being stripped at all. Is there something I need to do different to get the tags to be stripped?

A second question has to do with the `indexed` vs `stored` value. Since, as I mentioned above, you can have the indexed value be different from the original stored version, how can I see the difference between the two? If I'm doing a query in the Solr admin ui, which version of the field do I see? The indexed or the stored?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *stored* value is (usually) never changed (.. but [you can do that through an update chain if necessary](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_6_0//solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/HTMLStripFieldUpdateProcessorFactory.html) - but it sounds like that's not what you want), as long as you ask for it to be stored. The thing that matters for indexing is what tokens results from the content you're putting into the field. The content returned will not change or depend on which tokens are being indexed in the background for searching. The value returned by Solr is always (at least as long as the field is set as stored - docValues and "use as stored" could be different - I don't remember at the moment) the same as what you put into the field.

This also means that since you're sending HTML into the field as content, Solr will store the HTML as you're sending it in. You'll also have to reindex (resubmit) your content each time you change the definition of a field, except when you're only changing the `query` part of the analysis chain.

To see exactly how your field is being processed, go to your collection in the admin interface, select *Analysis* and paste the HTML into the "Indexed" (left) box. In the right box, enter `166` or another example of search strings used in your application. Select the field you want to show processing for, and press the submit button.

This will show exactly how each field is being processed, and what the result after each filter in the chain is. The resulting tokens are what matters, and these are what will generate a hit if present on both sides of the processing chain.

Comment: So basically, I can only see how it _would_ be indexed, not how it actually was. What I have above actually works (not sure why it didn't at first).